# how to use a javascript function to return an object in a node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have a problem in which i'm using a file to hold a list of modules and requiring this list in one call in my nodejs server. I want to use the modules in the list in a specific way.

modules.js -

```
Mods = {
  mymodule: require('./mymodule.js')
}

exports.f = function() {
  return Mods;
}
```

index.js -

```
f = require('./modules.js').f;

f().mymodule.echo("Hello World");
```

so instead of how i'm using f() now i want to put the name of the module i'm calling directly into the function so I can do things like this:

```
f = require('./modules.js').f;

f('mymodule').echo("Hello World");
```

I've tried a number of different experiments but can't get it to work, is it possible to do this in javascript?

Comment: Captain Zero, I suggest you work on your name, over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you do this:

```
var Mods = {
    mymodule: require('./mymodule.js');
}

module.exports = function( name ) {
    return Mods[name];
};
```

You can then do:

```
var f = require( "./modules.js"); //no .f required

f( "mymodule" ).echo( "Hello world");
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I was asked to explain my answer and I'm pleased to do so. The key to the solution is what is called the *bracket notation*. This term refers to the ability to access a property on an object in JavaScript using a variable. In the code below you can see how the property of the object `Mods` is accessed using `[name]` where `name` is a variable containing the name of the property as a string.

```
Mods = {
  mymodule: require('./mymodule.js');
}

exports.f = function(name) {
  return Mods[name];
}
```

Comment: Please think about adding a comment to your code only answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would say more ... ^^

```
var Mods = {
    mymodule: require('./mymodule.js');
}

module.exports = function( name ) {
  if( !name ) return Mods;
  return Mods[name];
};
```